# Why does keyring not unlock SSH?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, ssh-agent

When I use SSH to login on the network it asks for the password of id_rsa, even though I have keyring unlocked. What is going on, and how can I take steps to solve it?

Version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Gnome Version 3.36.8

Edit: This is the output of `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep ssh`:

```
Feb 12 10:43:49 Oven systemd[2571]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Feb 12 10:43:50 Oven systemd[2571]: ssh-agent.service: Succeeded.
Feb 12 10:44:03 Oven systemd[2029]: gpg-agent-ssh.socket: Succeeded.
Feb 12 10:44:03 Oven systemd[2029]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
```

After running `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` it starts, but it does not start on startup. After running the command above, it will not add my ssh-keys unless I run `ssh-add` and enter my password. How can I get that done automagically on logging in and entering my login password?

Comment: The lock on the keyring is to prevent other people from accessing your keys it doesn't mean that it unlocks the keys themselves.

If your using something like ssh-agent the default configuration is to ask for each private keys pass-phrase once.

Comment: Check if `id_rsa` is added to the `ssh-agent`.  Is the fingerprint of your key (get it with `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) also present in `ssh-add -l`? If you are not sure, you can add the output of these commands to the question if you like, the fingerprint is not private.

Comment: What does once mean in this context? After successfully logging in and exiting it asks for the password again

Comment: @pLumo whenever I run ssh-add in a new terminal it tells me the agent is not running. Do I need to auto-run it?

Comment: which ubuntu version?

Comment: @pLumo Added version info in the question

Comment: that is strange, it should start with X, do you have a file like this `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent` ?

Comment: @pLumo I do. Contents of the file: https://pastebin.com/FrjRyuC5. Should we move this to chat? (The site suggests it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119656/discussion-between-plumo-and-ananas-hoi).